# MongoDB query syntax max function

Tags: mongodb-query

How can I do a

`select max(field) from collection`  in MongoDB?

If this cannot be achieved, is there anything similar I can do?

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve it by:

```
db.collection.find({}).sort({"field" : -1}).limit(1)
```

or, to just get the max field value:

```
db.collection.find({}, {"_id":0, "field":1}).sort({"field" : -1}).limit(1)
```

This would find exactly one document with the highest value in `"field"`.

For more complex situations, you could try using [the MongoDB aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/).

I hope it helps at least slightly.